# where in clause and query multiple IDs using FuelPHP

Tags: php, crud, fuelphp

```
Model_Article::query()->where('id', 4);
```

I'm using FuelPHP. I have query like the above.

And I have an arrays of ID's

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 4, 8 ...);
```

How do I apply my array of id's to write this query using that format?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed the `'IN'` inside the `->where()` to create an `IN()` clause:

```
Model_Article::query()->where('field_name', 'IN', array(1,2,3,4,5))->get();
```